# R Writing prompt in a for loop to go back and change variables or proceed

Tags: r, if-statement, readline

I'm trying to write a prompt using `readline` and `if`/`else` so that I can either proceed if my data looks okay or go back and change variables if my data doesn't look okay.

I tried to make a reproducible example like below:

```
for (i in 1:10){
  y <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  print(min(y))
  ask<-readline(prompt="Enter 'y' if y_min is lower than -1")
  if(ask=='y'){#go back and change mean and sd of y#}else{#proceed to next line#}
}
```

In this example, I'm trying to make sure all `y` values are above -1 for each `i`. So if I print `min(y)` and if it gives me a value above -1, I'd answer `n` and proceed to the next line of code. Or if it gives me a value below -1, I'd answer `y` to the readline prompt and have it go back to the second line so that I can change `mean` and `sd` of `y`, try printing `min(y)` again, and either answer `y` or `n` and so on.

(I'm aware that there are simpler ways to ensure `y` doesn't go below -1 without using the `readline` prompt, but here I was just trying to come up with a simple reproducible example that I can post here)

I'm having trouble finding ways to have R go back to the line that I need to fix and re-run those lines again. Can anyone give me some advice on this?

Comment: Will you have an user to ask for y?

Comment: perhaps `if (ask == "y") { browser(); "update value, then continue"; } else { ...proceed...}`

Comment: @Bruno Yes I'm the user that answers `y` or `n` depending on what my printed `min(y)` value looks like